# schedule event run after 2 hour

Tags: java, android, spring-rest

My app is an Android app for booking tables.so the app directly communicating with the server.I need to call a specific event that is generated by the Android app.say an item is purchased by the Android app, so I need to hold that item for 2 hour so no one can use that item.i'm thinking change the flag inside the database to not available. After the use that is after 2 hour I need to release the item for the other users.

I know from trigger will done the job but is it possible to delete the crown trigger from the table and remove the scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you hold/release like that? It doesn't seem robust... if there's some kind of communication error, the bike could get hung up permanently.  I would run something based off timestamps and calculate the bike's availability in realtime based on the date. These calculations are going to be cheap to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle this on the client side then you have to do it using AlarmManager, schedule an event to make an api call or just release it locally. But as u said cron job will be a better way to do it where u update the db after 2 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to run particular Rest API

, after every 2 hr , You can either  set  [Repeating ALARM](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) , or you can user [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [Timer Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

OR

> If you want to just notify the user after 2 hr,

Then you can use cron-trigger with cloud messaging like FCM (firebase clod messaging )